# Issue with AWS ec2 instance ssh : error: AuthorizedKeysCommand

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, permissions

While trying to connect to my EC2 instance via ssh client, I got an error. I'm still able to connect from the option of  AWS console : EC2 Instance connect

> no supported authentication methods available server sent publickey,
> gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mac
>
> ec2-user@ip: Permission denied
> (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

There are errors in the status of that service

```
error: AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys ec2-user SHA256:fLnG8f1Ta+i7NYyr6Pih+rSv8Kum2uCZ40W1jxX3ihs failed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps and it solved my issue:

ssh-keygen -y -f  loginssh.pem

copy that key

```
#cloud-config
ssh_deletekeys: false
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - <ENTER YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE>
cloud_final_modules:
  - [ssh, always]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where is this YAML file that you are writing to, located?